# QGIS "Export/Add Geometry Columns..." not responding to redefining CRS

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, coordinates

I created a vector layer using the EPSG:3857 / Pseudo-Mercator CRS. After randomly sampling points within it, I am now trying to export their lat/long values in a different projection (e.g., a UTM based projection). It seems that redefining the layer CRS via either the:

`Rick-click on layer > Set CRS...`

or

`Vector > Data Management Tools > Define Current Projection...`

does not induce changes in the coordinates that are output by the:

`Vector > Geometry Tools > Export/Add Geometry Columns...`

function.

It appears that only saving the vector layer as a new layer with a new CRS will induce changes in the coordinates that are output.

Is this the appropriate behavior? Are the `Set CRS...` and `Define Current Projection...` functions purely for visualization? Can others confirm that this is the behavior that occurs for them when they follow the same workflow?

Using QGIS 2.14.8-Essen.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, changing the projection there does not actually alter the features in the layer. Coordinates will remain unchanged. It's just used to specify what crs those coordinates are in.

Comment: Is there a way to adjust coordinates apart from creating a new layer?